# how to fix Undefined variable: data on laravel view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-8

I am trying to send variable with data from a function to laravel front page view and i get Undefined variable: data (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\laravelproject\resources\views\process-url.blade.php).

This is my code and web.php routes.

web.php

```
Route::get('/',  [welcomechecker::class, 'getfrontpage']);
Route::post('process-url',  [welcomechecker::class, 'saveformdata']);
```

welcomechecker.php controller

```
class welcomechecker extends Controller
{

    function getfrontpage(){
        return view('welcome'); 
    }
```

function saveformdata(Request $request){

```
$client = new Client();

$data = [];
    
  $url = $request->url;   //getting value from ajax       $url =   $request->url; 
 
  $wp = $url.'/'.'wp-admin';
 
  $website = $client->request('GET', $url);

 $html = $website->html();

//Check if cms is wordpress
 
$cms  = '';

if($this->isWordPress($wp, $html) == 'WordPress'){

$cms  = 'WordPress';

 $data['cms'] = 'WordPress';
}
return view('process-url', compact('data'));
}
```

view blade: process-url.blade.php

```
@foreach($data as $student)
    {{$student->cms}}
@endforeach
```

front page view blade: welcome.blade.php

```
<div class="display-content alert-success" >
    @include('process-url')
</div>

application.js having ajax code

jQuery(document).ready(function(){

   $(document).ajaxStart(function(){
  $("#wait").css("display", "block");
  });
  $(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
  $("#wait").css("display", "none");
  });

          jQuery('#ajaxsubmit').click(function(e){
           e.preventDefault();
           
             jQuery('.alert').show();
           
           $.ajaxSetup({
              headers: {
                  'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
              }
          });
           jQuery.ajax({
              url: 'process-url',
             type: 'POST',
              data: {
                 url: jQuery('#enter_url').val()
               
              },
              success: function(result){
                  console.log(result);
                
                   jQuery('.display-content').html(result.success).fadeIn(700);
               
                // jQuery('.display-  content').html(result.success).fadeIn(700).fadeOut(5000);
              }});
           });
        });
```

Someone please help me to identify what i am doing wrong. I am trying to submit the variable data to the process-url blade view which is routed to the saveformdata() on the web.php. The error occurs in process-url.blade.php at the data variable. The saveformdata function has a whole lot of code than what i actually put here the whole idea is that it returns an array of data from a scraping tool which i want to display on a table on process-url blade

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: `return view('welcome'); ` does not contain any data?

Comment: That's the complete code for the `saveFormData` method? If so, you're trying to access each `$data` value as an object (`$student->cms`) while it is a string, as it is you can just refactor `$student->cms` to `$student` and it will work. If this isn't the main problem, try to add more info on the question, mainly by adding the complete error (message & line) and explaining all the logic you have on the method that's failing.

Comment: `return view('process-url', compact('data'));` in here `data` is an array and in the blade you try and access it like it was an object

Comment: @RiggsFolly, you may tell me a bit more about how the indentation of my code should be. I am happy to learn from you. return view('welcome') ; gives the welcome blade and the welcome blade includes the process-url blade to which the variable is sent.

Comment: @pmcpimentel, that is not the complete code or even the real code but the idea is getting a data from a variable after submitting a form through the saveformdata function and sending it to the process-url view which is then included to the welcome view as a sub view.

Comment: You could read the linked doc

Answer (score 0):

In the first URL you show a welcome blade file and it includes **process-url** blade without data variable

you should pass data variable in getfrontpage function like saveformdata
and the include directive pass variable to child blade

```php
function getfrontpage(){
        $data = ['Balloon Fight', 'Donkey Kong', 'Excitebike'];
 
        return view('welcome', compact('data'));
    }
```

and data variable array type that student will show every element in the array

```php
@foreach($data as $student)
    {{$student}}
@endforeach
```

Comment: please can you put some code for me to see.

Comment: The reason i am using saveformdata and not getfrontpage is because saveformdata actually gets data from a form scrape the data and puts the data to an array variable. saveformdata is using a post method in web.php. So now i need to send the data to process-url view and that is where i get undefined variable

Comment: But you include process-url in welcome blade file you can use @include('process-url', ['data' => [] ])

Answer (score 0):

Of course you will get Undefined Variable error when you are trying to include a blade file that is waiting for an array `$data` which is only passed to the view when you hit the route `process-url`. Also it is really, really bad practice to return a view after a POST request. Anyways, to solve your error (because that's what you actually want) you can do the following:

1. Pass the `$data` to the welcome page view and remove it from the process-url view

```
    function getfrontpage(){
        return view('welcome', [
           'data' => ['Balloon Fight', 'Donkey Kong', 'Excitebike']
        ]); 
    }

    function saveformdata(){
        return view('process-url');
    }
```

2. Pass the `$data` array from the welcome view to the process-url view through `@include`

```
<div class="display-content alert-success" >
    @include('process-url', ['data' => $data])
</div>
```

Your error now disappeared. Your code still makes no sense, but this is what you wanted.

Comment: Hi, i want to rather send from process-url to welcome view. The saveformdata function has a whole lot of code than what i actually put here the whole idea is that it returns an array of data from a scraping tool which i want to display on a table on process-url blade

Comment: The only way you access a GET route and in the same time send a POST request to another endpoint and receive its response is through AJAX request.

Comment: Actually i am doing this through ajax

Comment: Then your question is not relevant. You are showing totally different code. How are we supposed to help you?

Comment: No its not irrelevant. The basics is same. I have actually tried to send variable from m getfrontpage function and it works well. Just that, that is not what i want. it should be from saveformdata function

Comment: So as far as I understand the `@include('process-url')` presents an AJAX request to route `process-url` and the AJAX response is printed in the `.display-content` div, am I right? And the undefined variable error you're getting is actually on the `process-url` route?

Comment: Ok let me include the ajax request code to my question so you can see

Comment: Yes, that's the best thing you can do. Always include the full code so there is no misunderstanding like this

Comment: I added complete code for all to check. This is actually  done through an ajax request

Comment: I may just send code to database and do recall on view template. Well i wanted to avoid database operations.